# Existence of homoemorphism in [0,1] with special property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I hope you can help me. I'm interested in knowing if the existence of a homeomorphism $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$, **different** with $x^{\alpha}$, such that

- $f(0)=0$
- for every $x<y$ in $[0,1]$, there exists $n=n(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}$ with the following property
  $$f^n(x)<\frac{1}{2}f^n(y),$$

is possible. I think that this property is only true if $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha>1$.

Note $f^n=f\circ f\circ \cdots\circ f$. 
Any suggestion is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=e^{1-\frac{1}{x}}$, for $x>0$, and $f(0)=0$. You can think of it as $f(x)=x^{a(x)}$ where $a(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{x}-1}{\ln\frac{1}{x}}$. The reason to write it this way is that you can see as x approaches zero, the function behaves like a higher power of x. The higher the power, the greater the relative contraction of $x$ compared to $y$ where $x<y$.

This argument can be formalized but I leave that as an exercise to the reader. Please comment beilow if you wish for further details.